# Wordpress AWS route 53 setup

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, elastic-ip

I currently have wordpress installed on EC2 instance with an elastic IP. I have route 53 setup for an existing domain with a type A record set pointing to the elastic IP.

When I access the domain name in my browser, some of the web resources `(js, css files)` being loaded by the browser still point to the old public dns `(ec2-x-xx-xx-xxx.<zone>.compute.amazonaws.com)`, so they fail to load and the site does not fully loaded. How do I fix this?

Comment: The old DNS is probably configured somewhere in WordPress. You might get a better response asking at: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: you can check this link https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/245349/change-urls-for-static-content

Comment: have you change `site_url` params in `wp_options` table  or `wp-config.php` just check once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hosting-wordpress.html). Under the section 'Help! My Public DNS Name Changed and now my Blog is Broken'.

The reason I was having this issue in the first place was because I switched my EC2 IP to elasticIP after I installed and setup wordpress. So wordpress had the old IP in its installation. If I had setup the elasticIP before installing wordpress I would not have had this issue. But the above the link helped me solve it.